# Sum of vector elements

Tags: r, vector, sum

Is it possible to avoid using do and while loops to calculate the sum of the elements of a vector until the appearance of the last positive element or the last negative element.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
x <- 5:-5
# sum until last positive:
sum(x[1:max(which(x > 0))])

x <- -5:5
# sum until last negative:
sum(x[1:max(which(x < 0))])
```

Explanation:

`Which(x > 0)` gives a vector of index numbers at which x is greater than 0. Taking the max of this gives the last such index. Then all that remains is summing up x from 1 up to this element. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is what I needed. What did u wanted me to do Tyler.

Comment: Edward, I am happy to explain, its a vector which is randomly generated. I need to find the sum of all the elements until the appearnce of the first postive number. Thanks for your help

Comment: Edward, Shouldnt there be min instead of max for the last negative one. And I want the sum of all the elements until the appearance of the last neagative element.

Comment: For the first appearance, use `min`. For the last appearance, use `max`.

Comment: Ali here's a [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example.  it'll get you better results and faster.

Comment: There's also `which.max` which handles this common use case.

Comment: @Edward this fails when x has length 0, or no elements satisfy the condition.

Comment: That's a good point Martin, definitely should be taken into consideration. You could do something like: `end.range <- which(x > 0)` and then do checking as follows: `if (length(end.range) == 0){sum(x)} else {sum(x[1:max(end.range)])}` (it would obviously depend on what you want the behavior to be in the case of this exception). Thanks for pointing it out.