# Summing Vector elements until a Positive element is encountered - R

Tags: r, sum

I'm new to R and I'm looking through a book called "Discovering Statistics using R".
Although the book implies you don't need any statistical background, some of the content isn't covered/explained...

I'm trying to sum the elements of a vector starting from position 1 until a positive element is present.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846620/sum-of-vector-elements) question which is very similar to what I'm trying to achieve. However when I implement it, it doesn't always seem to work (and it sometimes appears to include the first positive element)...

My program is:

```
  vecA <- runif(10, -10, 10);
  sumA <-sum(vecA [1:min(which(vecA < 0))]);
```

Is there a more robust way to calculate this without using loops that works every time and doesn't add the positive element? I'm not at the looping stage of my books yet.

I also found [this](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/1287th4gs4/r-sum-of-vector-elements) site which asks a similar question but their answer errors:

```
  sum(vecA [seq_len(which.max(vecA > 0)]);
```

Comment: What you're doing is perhaps the simplest way. The answers in the comments are good, but over complicated, making it difficult to understand a simple idea.

Comment: What is your desired output if the first element is positive (there are no elements to sum)?

Comment: @BlueMagister I assume it should return 0? That seems reasonable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use > not < to sum all elements until the first positive one is reached.

You're currently summing from 1 until the first negative value is reached (including the first negative value).

```
sum(vecA[1:min(which(vecA>0))-1])
```

the which() function will return all of the positions of the positive elements, then taking the sum from 1 to the position of the first positive - 1 will guarantee you are summing all of the negative elements

Comment: Oh! silly mistake. It makes sense now. Thanks for taking the time post. Very good answer. :)

Comment: Would this also work if all elements are negative like the answer below?

Comment: @Reanimation No, it does not work if all elements are negative.

Comment: Ah that's ok. I was just checking I wasn't doing something stupid in R when I was trying it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
sum(vecA * !cumsum(vecA > 0))
```

This also works if the first element is positive or all elements are negative.

Comment: Ah. Thanks great. I've not seen the `cumsum()` function before. Thanks for posting.

Comment: This is a great answer, upboats for your use of ! my friend

Answer (score 1):

match function is usually the fastest to find the first occurrence of some element in a vector, so another version of this could look like follows:

```
first.positive <- match(TRUE, vecA > 0)
sumA <- sum( vecA[ 1 : first.positive ] ) - vecA[first.positive]
```

This will give you zero if positive element is the first.